# Required field error message when creating a wiki page , even if all the required fields have values

Tags: list, publishing-site, library, enterprise-wiki

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection, and i added six managed metadata columns. the problem i am facing is that when i create a new wiki page , and i try saving it , i will get the following error:-

> You must fill out all required properties before completing this
>   action.

although i have filled all the required fields, please can anyone advice ?

Thanks

Comment: make sure their is no hidden fields or a field may be missed on the new item page? did you customize it?

Comment: also check this link http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/what-about-you-must-fill-out-all-required-properties-before-completing-this-action-when-publishing-a-page/

Comment: i am sure all the required fields are not null, and even after receiving the error , i will be redirected to another page,and without entering any data i will be able to save the page.. so the error message is not valid..

Comment: check the 2nd link i think he is talking about same issue

Comment: thanks for the link, i already read it ,, but i am not sure how i can create the control? should I do this inside the visual studio ? and how i will be referencing it inside the page layout ?